# Pythonic way of searching for a substring in a list

Tags: string, list, python, substring

I have a list of strings - something like

```
mytext = ['This is some text','this is yet more text','This is text that contains the substring foobar123','yet more text']
```

I want to find the first occurrence of anything that starts with foobar.  If I was grepping then I would do search for foobar*.  My current solution looks like this

```
for i in mytext:
    index = i.find("foobar")
    if(index!=-1):
        print i
```

Which works just fine but I am wondering if there is a 'better' (i.e more pythonic) way of doing this?

Cheers,
Mike

Comment: Your code and your comments are not aligned.  :)  You say you want "anything that starts with foobar" (hence @THC4k's answer), but your code prints all strings containing "foobar" anywhere (hence others' answers).

Comment: Agreed - I wasn't careful enough in phrasing my question.  I'll not correct it though so future generations can see that I'm the stupid one rather than those who answered.

Sorry guys and thanks for all the answers.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can also use a list comprehension :

```
matches = [s for s in mytext if 'foobar' in s]
```

(and if you were really looking for strings *starting* with 'foobar' as THC4k noticed, consider the following :

```
matches = [s for s in mytext if s.startswith('foobar')]
```

Comment: Now I'm wondering if doing this as a generator is better: matches = (s for s in mytext if s.startswith('foobar')) Anyone knows?

Comment: @Koen It's better to use a generator if (a) the result list would be large (although it would only consist of references to the original strings), and (b) you do not need to have the result in one piece, e.g. to do a len(matches) or a matches[-1], but rather want to iterate through it.

Answer (score 10):

If you really want the FIRST occurrence of a string that STARTS WITH foobar (which is what your words say, though very different from your code, all answers provided, your mention of grep -- how contradictory can you get?-), try:

```
found = next((s for s in mylist if s.startswith('foobar')), '')
```

this gives an empty string as the `found` result if no item of mylist meets the condition. You could also use itertools, etc, in lieu of the simple genexp, but the key trick is this way of using the `next` builtin with a default (Python 2.6 and better only).

Comment: +1 I was just cracking my head over a (s for s in...)[0] expression, to get just the first item, and wondered what to do if there is no first item...

Comment: @ThomasH, yeah, in 2.5 you had to do a `try: / x=blah.next() / except StopIteration`, 2.6's builtin `next` is much handier!

Answer (score 6):

```
for s in lst:
    if 'foobar' in s:
         print(s)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
results = [ s for s in lst if 'foobar' in s]
print(results)
```

Answer (score 4):

in case you really looking for strings that **start** with foobar ( not with foobar **in**  them):

```
for s in mylist:
  if s.startswith( 'foobar' ):
     print s
```

or

```
found = [ s for s in mylist if s.startswith('foobar') ]
```