# Test multiple substrings against a string

Tags: python

If I have an list of strings:

```
matches = [ 'string1', 'anotherstring', 'astringystring' ]
```

And I have another string that I want to test:

```
teststring = 'thestring1'
```

And I want to test each string, and if any match, do something.  I have:

```
match = 0
for matchstring in matches:
  if matchstring in teststring:
    match = 1
if !match:
  continue
```

This is in a loop, so we just go around again if we don't get a match (I can reverse this logic of course and do something if it matches), but the code looks clumsy and not pythonic, if easy to follow.

I am thinking there is a better way to do this, but I don't grok python as well as I would like.  Is there a better approach?

Note the "duplicate" is the opposite question (though the same answer approach is the same).

Comment: you need full or partial match?

Comment: `if any(match in teststring for match in matches)`

Comment: @viakondratiuk the 'in' does a substring match

Comment: FWIW using a compiled regex  would probably be faster than any and allow you to return any matched substring

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Thanks, yes, I am not concerned about speed here, and in this instance I don't need to know what the match was, only that it matched.  So if either of these aren't true in future, regex.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham so what would you be doing converting list to str using str and then apply regex ?.

Comment: @The6thSense,  `r = re.compile(r"|".join(matches))` then use r. r.pattern will be  `'string1|anotherstring|astringystring'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pythonic way of searching for a substring in a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260947/pythonic-way-of-searching-for-a-substring-in-a-list)

Answer (score 6):

You could use [**`any`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19389490/how-pythons-any-and-all-functions-work) here

**Code:**

```
if any(matchstring in teststring for matchstring in matches):
    print "Matched"
```

**Notes:**

- [**`any`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19389490/how-pythons-any-and-all-functions-work) exits as soon it see's a match.
- As per as the loop what is happening is `for matchstring in matches` here each string from the `matches` is iterated.
- And here `matchstring in teststring` we are checking if the iterated string is in the defined check string.
- The `any` will exit as soon as it see's a  `True`[match] in the expression.

Comment: Yes, I wasn't aware of `any`

Comment: Though I cannot follow the `x in y for x in z` - how is that working?

Comment: `in` operator for strings checks for substring occurence, `for o in seq` iterates over sequence. These are two different functionalities with same keyword used.

Comment: @Rogalski Yes, I understand the two uses of `in`, I just don't understand how the matchstring created in the `for` can be tested at the beginning

Comment: @Paul added see if it makes sense.

Comment: @Paul it's simply how scopes in comprehensions are designed. See related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20639180/python-list-comprehension-explained

Comment: @The6thSense I understand what it is doing, I just don't understand the underlying mechanic that allows the output from the `for` iterator be used in a test that precedes it on the line.

Comment: @Paul that is the syntax for `list,dict,set etc.,.` comprehension. You may want to look at the link given by Rogalski.

Comment: @The6thSense Yes, I did (thanks Rogalski), I am absorbing.

Comment: It was confusing for me too initially when I came across `comprehension.`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know what the first match was you can use [**`next`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next):

```
match = next((match for match in matches if match in teststring), None)
```

You have to pass `None` as the second parameter if you don't want it to raise an exception when nothing matches. It will use the value as the default, so `match` will be `None` if nothing is found.

Answer (score 0):

How about you try this:

```
len([ x for x in b if ((a in x) or (x in a)) ]) > 0
```

I've updated the answer to check the substring both ways. You can pick and choose or modify as you see fit but I think the basics should be pretty clear.

Comment: This would evaluate every string in matches even if you matched the first string and create a list to throw away.

Comment: True that it goes a step further in also counting the matches and maybe not required for this step but then again it might be.

Comment: sum with a generator expression would also count the matches and avoid the need to store a list, this is not  a use case for a list comp and len.